# Merge tag [resource-disposal] into [disposal]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

They seem to have identical meaning. I can't think of what you could dispose besides resources in a programming context, so *resource* can be safely discarded.

Comment: You could always dispose of old hardware... and use software to write a program to do it!